# How can I find out whether the Field List is currently visible in a DevExpress PivotGrid control

Tags: devexpress-wpf

I am wanting to use a toggle button to show or hide the Field List in a pivotgrid, but to do this (and show appropriate tooltips) I need to know whether the field list is currently visible or not. Is there an easy way to do this? It feels like it should be straightforward, but I cannot find any property that indicates the current visibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use the Pivot.IsFieldListVisible property, which I couldn't see on looking. In case anyone else is a blind as me.